# django-admin command : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'

Tags: django, module, django-admin, settings

I have seen multiple post about that problem but I still can't fix it.

I have tried:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings.dev
```

but when I try

```
django-admin test
```

I get that error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

I also tried to add the variable to my environment variables (that works) but I keep receiving that error.

Here's where my settings file is located (dev imports base).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add your project's absolute path to environment variable `PYTHONPATH`

```
PS > $env:PYTHONPATH += ";d:/Github/django-labs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you be missing a **init**.py file inside the `mysite` folder?
Can't see that from the photo

Comment: The command: django-admin version works well

Comment: but my initial intention was to run: django-admin flush